# Is there a way to get the active categories from jQuery Filterizr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a single item unless a category is selected. I'm using the `filteringStart` callback to do this. How do I get the active categories array from the filterizr object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a public method to get active filters in the Filterizr library. It isn't too difficult to write the JavaScript required to figure it out though.

Using one of their examples, the html would look as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-gallery filters-filteringModeSingle" id="filteringModeSingle">
    <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="all">All</li>
    <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="green">Green</li>
    <li class="filtr-button filtr filtr-active" data-fltr="orange">Orange</li>
    <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="purple">Purple</li>
    <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="mix">Mix</li>
</ul>
```

You could get an array of selected values as follows:

```
var selected = $.map($(".filtr-active").toArray(), function(el, i) {
    return $(el).data("fltr");
});
```

To do something based on a specific value being selected, you could do the following:

```
if (selected.indexOf("green") !== -1) {
    console.log("You selected green!");
}
```

I hope that makes sense!

Edit:

You could get the unselected filters by tweaking the selector.

```
var notSelected = $.map($(".filtr:not(.filtr-active)").toArray(), function (el, i) {
    return $(el).data("fltr");
});
```

Comment: Good call, Wayne. Hadn't noticed the flitr-active class.

Comment: However, I just tried it and that class is for doesn't get set. There is an inverse of that class called filteredOut that gets set on the other ones so maybe I can work with that.

Comment: @IAmNaN I've updated the answer with a selector for getting the unselected filters :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(function () { 
   console.log($(this)[0].getAttribute("data-filter"));
});
```